# Created a search form that adds conditions to a sql query but is returning 0 results due to 'AND' statement

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a search form that contains checkboxes, a user selects the checkboxes which then filters out the results that are shown.

At the moment it works to some extent, however, due to the 'AND' statement, it's returning 0 results.

For example

Let's say as an example my database has a column called vibes and I have 2 records,

```
name         | vibes
Brunch1      | Party Animal, Music Maniac, Arty        
Brunch2      | Arty, Party Animal
```

and let's say the user has selected the checkboxes for Party Animal, Arty

it returns 'Brunch 1 and Brunch2' however if the users select the `Touristy` checkbox and submit the form, it returns 0 results, because there it's checking if `Brunch1` and `Brunch2` have `Touristy` in the vibes column.

I'm assuming it's to do with it adding the AND statement, this is what the SQL query is currently looking like once you click submit ...

```
SELECT b.*, host FROM brunches b LEFT JOIN hosts ON hosts.id = 
b.hostid WHERE approved ='1' AND vibes LIKE '%Arty%' AND vibes LIKE 
'%Party Animal%' AND vibes LIKE '%Touristy%'
```

My php code

```
$brunches = "SELECT b.*, host
FROM brunches b
LEFT JOIN hosts ON hosts.id = b.hostid  ";
$conditions = array();


$conditions[] = "approved ='1'";


if(! empty($vibes)) {
   foreach($vibes as $tag):
     $conditions[] = "vibes LIKE '%$tag%'";
   endforeach;
}

$sql = $brunches;
   if (count($conditions) > 0) {
   $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}

$sql= $this->db->query($sql);
```

I beleive that because it's using AND instead of OR,

However, I have other fields in the search form like 'name' so that does require it to be like WHERE name = '' AND approved = '1' AND vibe= ''

e.t.c

hope this makes sense.

Comment: Use OR after the first AND

Comment: but it's automatically adding the AND for each condition, so not sure what I could do

Comment: This is one of the core reasons to normalize your tables and not store them as comma-separated values. If you had them split out into rows, you could simply use `... WHERE vibes IN ('some', 'thing', 'else')`

Comment: But wouldn't that just get messy, let's say one record has 30 vibes, you'd have a row for each one right?

Comment: `but it's automatically adding the AND...` -  no, you're telling it to separate the conditions with an _and_. You need to split out your logic further to handle the _vibes_ condition.

Comment: `wouldn't that just get messy` - on the contrary, your PHP would be simpler. This is known as a _one-to-many_ relationship and is a foundational concept in database design.

Comment: Nigel seems to have you covered ;-)

Comment: A decent explanation - https://www.lifewire.com/one-to-many-relationships-1019756

Answer (score 2):

You could add the approved = 1 as hardcoded in the `where` clause, adding the `like` parts in brackets and linked by `OR` instead of `AND`.  I've also moved the part where it adds the `WHERE` into the `if` which creates the `conditions` values...

```
$sql = $brunches;
if(! empty($vibes)) {
    $conditions = [];
    foreach($vibes as $tag) {
        $conditions[] = "vibes LIKE '%$tag%'";
    }
    $sql .= PHP_EOL."WHERE approved ='1' and (" . implode(' OR ', $conditions).")";
}
```

which generates something like...

```
SELECT b.*, host
FROM brunches b
LEFT JOIN hosts ON hosts.id = b.hostid   
WHERE approved ='1' and (vibes LIKE '%a%' OR vibes LIKE '%b%')
```